# Electron reactjs app show empty page after reloading if user navigate to other route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I create my project with `create-react-app`. I use `react-router-dom` for router and `electron-builder` to package my app.

When I first run my application, it works normally but once I reload the page all becomes white. If I don't navigate to other routes, the app still works after reloading.

Below is my electron/index.js code

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 600,
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 200,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    useContentSize: true,
    resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev
    ? 'http://localhost:3000'
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
  mainWindow.focus();

  mainWindow.on('close', (e) => {
    if (willQuitApp) {
      /* the user tried to quit the app */
      mainWindow = null;
    } else {
      /* the user only tried to close the window */
      e.preventDefault();
      mainWindow.hide();
    }
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I only need to use `<HashRouter>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>`

Comment: <BrowserRouter> can open for the first time and go blank, <HashRouter> goes blank from first.

Answer (score -1):

You got empty page after reloading because when you navigate to another page, you change the url. So when you reload, electron will load that url instead of `index.html` file